# HttpUrlConnection getResponseCode throws IOException

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I got IOException when i try call getCodeResponse(). When parameters are valid there is no exception and code response is 200. In case of wrong parameteres server should return 401 code. I've tested query on hurl.it and in case of wrong parameters i got 401 code. Maybe HttpURLConnection class throws exception when error code occurs.

```
        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod(methodType);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.addRequestProperty(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING, ENCODING_GZIP);

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os));

            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            //os.write(query.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

            if(conn != null){

                responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                result = readResponse(conn);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The IOException means that there is a 401 response. Print the stacktrace and if everything else is correct, it'll give a 401 response. Something like : `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:`